# Unable to resolve dependency tree when installing @angular/material

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to install `@angular/material` module but I keep getting this error whenever I run :

```
$ npm install --save @angular/material
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: front@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^9.1.11" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0-0" from @angular/material@11.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!   @angular/material@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Any help will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try as mentioned:

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps

**[More Details.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install#configuration-options-affecting-dependency-resolution-and-tree-design)**

Comment: I have tried it, it says `up to date in 3s`. Now when I run again `$ npm install --save @angular/material` I keep getting the same error message as above.

Answer (score 0):

run "npm install --force" under your project.